# How to add key to existing dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python3 and trying to figure out the easiest way to add another layer to my dictionary. I have a dictionary that looks like this.

`{ "block1": ["brian"], "block2": ["angel"], "block3": ["sally"] }`

How can I add name into the existing dictionary?

`{ "name": { "block1": [ "brian" ], "block2": [ "angel" ], "block3": [ "sally" ] } }`

Comment: What's your desired output? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
d1 = { "block1": ["brian"], "block2": ["angel"], "block3": ["sally"] }

d1 = {"name":d1}

print (d1)
```